# Saving Python array with np save - size issue

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, saving-data

I appear to be having an issue saving a data array delivered by an API call.

The data arrives in the following array format:

```
(ArrayOfTrackStruct){
   data[] = 
      (TrackStruct){
         timestamp = 1469493614
         latitude = 29.97889
         longitude = -90.20583
      },
      (TrackStruct){
         timestamp = 1469493683
         latitude = 29.97445
         longitude = -90.11833
      },
    ...
      (TrackStruct){
         timestamp = 1469493745
         latitude = 30.04445
         longitude = -90.09417
      },
}
```

I can load and work with the data just fine, e.g., assigning to variable track and accessing track[0][2] will give me the time, lat and long of the third element.

However, when saving with:

```
track = api.service.GetLastTrack(str(item))
outfile = "NumpyScratch1.npy"
np.save(outfile, track, allow_pickle=True, fix_imports=True)
```

I get the following error: ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 284 to array axis with dimension 2

Clearly a dimensioning issue.  Any ideas on means to either reformat the array to a np.save compatible format, or other means to save and later load the data array?

Comment: This doesn't look like a `numpy` data structure. You could just (c)pickle it.

Comment: What's the shape and dtype of `track`?  If it isn't an array with those attributes, why are you trying to use `np.save`?  Have you tried a straight `pickle`?